# Django settings are not configured

Tags: python, django

I just uninstalled python 3.6 and installed python 3.7 and as i install django into a virtual environment and then type django-admin it brings out this error.

```bash
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured(error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured.You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

then when i try django-admin runserver it shows

```bash
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured.You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the django documentation:

> When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you’re using.
>   Do this by using an environment variable, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
>
> The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax,
>   e.g. **mysite.settings**. Note that the settings module should be on the
>   Python import search path.

**Example (Windows shell):**

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
django-admin runserver
```

Please refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to use `manage.py` instead of `django-admin`, because `manage.py` takes care of setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` for you.

Start the project with `django-admin`:

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

But after that, use `manage.py` instead, e.g.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```